# How to install HP LaserJet P2015 on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Does anybody know how to install driver for old printer HP LaserJet P2015 on Windows 10 x64?

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? HP has Windows 10 x64 drivers for that printer on their site. Are you getting errors while installing them?

Comment: When I'm trying to install this driver, on the screen "Select an installation mode for the HP Universal Printing...", I choose "USB mode - Plug and Play", but after connecting printer it does not appear in the "Devices and Printers" folder.

Comment: Maybe bad cable? Does it show up at all in Device Manager?

Comment: I checked the cable, on another PC with Windows XP the printer is working!

Comment: Is [this](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-p2015-printer-series/1845551/model/1845552) the driver you installed on your Windows 10 system?

Comment: Yes! It's the same driver.

Comment: Try install HP Universal Printer Driver (UPD) for PCL6 or PostScript (PS) at:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-laserjet-p2015-printer-series/1845551/model/1845...